# Routing stops working on prod react + node

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, routes

After `npm run build` client stops redirecting to certain pages (`/about`, `/home` after successful login etc).

During development, every stage is successful, however.

Project structure:

`--client
  --build
  --src
    --containers
      --App.js
    index.js
  --other dev stuff
--server
  --server.js
    --routes
      --svrRoutes.js 
  --other stuff`

`App.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        //
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Router>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path="/" exact component={Login} />
                        <Route path="/dashboard" component={withAuthentication(Dashboard)} />
                        <Route path="/about" component={About} />
                        <Route path="/home" component={withAuthentication(Home)} />
                        <Route path="/searchtweets" component={SearchTweets} />

                    </Switch>
                </Router>
                <Footer1/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

`svrRoutes.js`

```
let {
    addNewData,
    getData,
    getDataByID,
    updateDataByID,
    deleteDataByID,
    addNewUser,
    getUserByID,
    getUser,
    updateUserByID,
    getDataByManID
} = require('../controllers/svrController');

let {
    getTweetData
} = require('../twitter');

const routes = (app) => {


    app.route('/data')
        .get((req, res, next) => {
            // middleware
            console.log(`Request from: ${req.originalUrl}`);
            console.log(`Request type: ${req.method}`);
            next();
        }, getData)

        // POST endpoint
        .post(addNewData);

    app.route('/data/twitter')
        .get((req, res) => {
            getTweetData(req, res);
        });

    app.route('/data/:dataId')
        // get specific data Item
        .get(getDataByID)
        // put request
        .put(updateDataByID)
        // delete request
        .delete(deleteDataByID);

    app.get('/getdata', getDataByManID);

    app.route('/user')
        .post(addNewUser)

        .get((req, res, next) => {
            // middleware
            console.log(`Request from: ${req.originalUrl}`);
            console.log(`Request type: ${req.method}`);
            next();
        }, getUser);
    app.route('/user/:userId')
        .get(getUserByID)
    // put request
        .put(updateUserByID);
    app.route('/man/:userId')
        .get(getDataByManID);
};

module.exports = routes;
```

Here's the repo on GitHub, I believe it's better than posting just snippets since I can miss something important.
https://github.com/aaronjohn2/EmployerDatabaseViewApplication

Comment: Do you use React Router? If so please post the code here, and server side routing as well.

Comment: updated the post with react router and server

Comment: What happens instead of rendering the `/about` and `/home` pages? Any error, other route?